# How do I add a date using C# & SQL to an MS Access database with column type 'Date/Type'?

Tags: c#, date, ms-access, datetimepicker, insert-into

I have tried using a `DateTimePicker` with format `dd/MM/yyyy` to insert a date into a `Date/Time` column in my MS Access database using the insert SQL statement.

Here is what I have done:

```
connection.Open();

OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
command.Connection = connection; // Connecting the command to the connection.
command.CommandText = "insert into [TestEntry] (TestTableID, StudentID, DateOfTest, [DeadLine]) values(" + int.Parse(txtTestName.Text) + ", " + int.Parse(studentID) + ", #" + this.dateTimeStartD.Text + "# , #" + this.dateTimeEndD.Text + "#)";

command.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
```

I keep getting the error

> Input string was not in correct format

The Date/Time columns in my Access table are formatted as 'Short date' eg. 12/11/2015.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: That is not how you pass values to Access; [use parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893837/).

Comment: I have been using this way to insert values into my Access tables through out my program and have had no issues. I think I am getting the error because I am not passing the date data from the dateTimePicker correctly.

Comment: it would be better for you to follow this instructions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402173/sql-statement-with-datetimepicker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think its coming from database level. This exception is coming when you try to case value which in different format. Please check you first argument for the insert statement.

```
int.Parse(txtTestName.Text)
```

You are trying to insert integer value to "TestTableID" field by converting text box value to integer. Please check your text box input is number or characters. It should be only numbers.